# when submitting for review on iTunes connect I got this

Tags: ios, xcode, build, submit, beta

when submitting for review on iTunes connect I got this:

New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, OS X, and iOS SDK. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta OS X builds.

My Xcode is Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)
OS X 10.11 (15A2301)
iOS SDK is iOS 9.2

I didn't use any beta version!!

Comment: Unusual. Are you including any frameworks that could have been built with beta versions of Xcode? I think that you need to post on the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Do a full clean build and try again.

Comment: I included storeKit framework..I already cleaned many times...should I disable bit code?

Comment: still can't make it work..I am so frustrated...I downgraded to Xcode 7.2 still ddient work...

Comment: solved when upgrading to OS X 10.11.3.  help say it is a bud for not supporting OS X 10.11 for new computer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your command line tools is not beta

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Apple's backend is not yet validating Xcode 7.2.1. This has happened in the past. You have 2 options - wait for Apple to get things squared away with 7.2.1 (one would think that should be any day now). Or, submit your app using [Xcode 7.2](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7.2/Xcode_7.2.dmg).

Comment: I actually used 7.1 before but still have this problem..so I upgraded to 7.2.1